Kali Linux-Headers not being installed due to rtl8188fu
I am not able to install the linux-headers-6.8.11-amd64 kernel even after repeated trying. I tried several methods - sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade, sudo apt-get dist-upgrade, sudo dkms --configure linux-headers-amd64 ,sudo apt-get install linux-headers-amd64, sudo apt install linux-image-amd64; but to no avail. I have also seen sveral of the previous questions on this site like link1, link2.  In addition, the error the terminal shows is as follows:
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.8.11-amd64 (--configure):
installed linux-headers-6.8.11-amd64 package post-installation 
script subprocess returned error exit status 11
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-amd64:
linux-headers-amd64 depends on linux-headers-6.8.11-amd64 
(=   6.8.11-1kali2); however:
Package linux-headers-6.8.11-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-amd64 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-6.8.11-rt-amd64-dbg (6.8.11-1kali2) ...
Setting up linux-image-6.8.11-rt-amd64 (6.8.11-1kali2) ...
I: /initrd.img.old is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-6.8.11-rt-amd64
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.11-rt-amd64.
Sign command: /lib/modules/6.8.11-rt-amd64/build/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
Building module(s)....................(bad exit status: 2)
Failed command:
'make' all KVER=6.8.11-rt-amd64
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 
6.8.11-rt-amd64   (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8188fu/1.0/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.11-rt-amd64/x86_64 failed for rtl8188fu(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
dkms: autoinstall for kernel: 6.8.11-rt-amd64 failed!

From the errors, I feel the wifi driver rtl8188fu is the one that creates trouble. But, it is the driver for the wifi adapter for my PC, and deleting it would mean no internet for me. So, how should I proceed. For information, I currently have linux-header uname -a version as 6.6.9. Rebooting will log me to the latest version Kali Linux 6.8.11, but without wifi drivers in the ifconfig, and without internet connection. For reference, here is first few lines of the content of the /var/lib/dkms/rtl8188fu/1.0/build/make.log file:
DKMS make.log for rtl8188fu-1.0 for kernel 
6.8.11-cloud-amd64 (x86_64)
Friday 12 July 2024 04:51:10 PM IST
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C 
/lib/modules/6.8.11- cloud-amd64/build 
M=/var/lib/dkms /rtl8188fu/1.0/build  modules
make[1]: Entering directory 
'/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.11-cloud-amd64'
CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8188fu/1.0/build/core/rtw_cmd.o
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8188fu/1.0/build/core/rtw_cmd.c:2225:4:     warning: no previous prototype for ‘_rtw_set_chplan_cmd’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
 2225 | u8 _rtw_set_chplan_cmd(_adapter *adapter,  
int  flags,       u8 chplan, const struct 
country_chplan  *country_ent, u8 swconfig)
  |    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8188fu/1.0/build/core/rtw_cmd.c:2769:6:  warning: no previous prototype for ‘dynamic_chk_wk_hdl’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2769 | void dynamic_chk_wk_hdl(_adapter *padapter)
  |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8188fu/1.0/build/core/rtw_cmd.c:2963:6:   warning: no previous prototype for ‘rtw_dm_in_lps_hdl’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2963 | void rtw_dm_in_lps_hdl(_adapter*padapter)
  |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8188fu/1.0/build/core/rtw_cmd.c:3004:6: warning: no previous prototype for ‘rtw_lps_change_dtim_hdl’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
 3004 | void rtw_lps_change_dtim_hdl
(_adapter *padapter, u8 dtim)
  |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

For the full file, as it is very large, the link to open in Drive is here
Any hints?

So, how should I proceed. ... forget Kali and install a user friendly Linux distribution, such as Ubuntu or Mint

@jsotola for your kind information, this is not a beginner issue, and is also reported in bug. Anyways, I seem to have solved the issue partly. Will post an answer mostly in the coming days. By the way, I am using Kali for 2+years, and it is great. Just 'forgetting' Kali for this issue would mean loss of several files and processes, which I would have to reinstall in the other OS. And, this seems to be a general linux-kernel, rather than kali-specific problem.

I was able to solve the problem by getting rid/purging of the problem creating header files and their corollaries. To so this, I used the Synaptic package manager. The method using terminal and aptitude was not completely successful in my case. Some methods to purge unwanted header files can be found here.
By the way, the issue in OP was also pointed out in kali bugs. Hence, this link will also prove useful for those having similar problems.
